# Pasar Funciones con module exports discordjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de ejecutar funciones desde otro archivo hacia mi codigo fuente para dejarlo mas limpio pero no se como hacerlo el codigo es el siguiente:

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed, message} = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var db = require('quick.db');

db = new db.table('jorgitojoestar1')

    function uno_a_tres() {

    var stands1 = [('spf()'), ('tw()')];
    var stands2 = [('hg()'), ('mr()'), ('tf()'), ('ho()'), ('cr()'), ('sc()')];
    var stands3 = [('dbm()'), ('hm()'), ('wof()'), ('dt()'),('ju()')];
    var stands4 = [('ed()'), ('em()'), ('hpr()'), ('se()')];
    var stands5 = [('es()'), ('jm()'), ('an()'), ('os()')];
    var stands6 = [('hp()'), ('tog()'), ('yt()'), ('lo()'), ('geb()'), ('ba()'), ('at()'), ('kh()'), ('th()'), ('str()')];

    }

    function spf() {

      const starplatinumE = new MessageEmbed()

      .setTitle(message.author.username + " | Obtuviste a: Star Platinum (10 Segs.)")
      .setColor(0xDD03FF)
      .setImage("https://media.giphy.com/media/xqGaLI0qmmQ6LseYpj/giphy.gif");  

      db.set(`${message.author.id}.stands`, 'Star Platinum' );
      db.set(`${message.author.id}.vida`, 1300 );
      db.set(`${message.author.id}.ataque`, 400 );
      db.set(`${message.author.id}.hab1n`, 'Ora Ora Ora!' );

      spa();

    return starplatinumE;
    }

    module.exports = uno_a_tres()
```

la funcion uno_a_tres lleva mas funciones pero no las subo todas para no hacer tan pesado el código ya con 1 se entiende quiero exportar la función uno_a_tres como lo hago? gracias

pd: no me deja cargar stackoverflow todo el codigo de la funcion uno_a_tres porque sino no lo puedo subir por eso no lo puse todo, los errores que me tira son porque faltan los arumentos de message o de embed, por eso necesito ayuda en eso porque no se como se usa module.exports

Comment: Estás exportando el resultado de tu función y no la función. Quita los paréntesis que pones al final de la sentencia `module.exports`. Debería ser solamente: `module.exports = uno_a_tres;`

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por tu respuesta, gracias me funciono pero ahora me dice que no puede leer las propiedas como message o author como las puedo declarar? tenes algun ejemplo?